# O que é um Repository? Pra que serve?

Tags: php

Gostaria de uma explicação a cerca do que é um Repository. Cruzei com o termo num curso online que estou fazendo, mas não entendi direito...

Comment: Repositório é como um backup do seu código. Você tem uma pasta original(que é seu repositório origin) e seu master(que é o repositório onde você trabalha/codifica). Sempre que você terminar uma alteração/modulo no seu código, você manda as alterações do seu master para o origin, e caso aconteça algum problema no seu master, você pode recuperar através do seu repositório origin. Em grosso modo, pode fala que seu repositório é seu  backup de versões do seu projeto/código.